# i set height 100% to element? and it not working

Tags: html, css

```css
.landing {
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 72px);
  background-color: orange;
}

.landing .container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height:100%;
}
.landing .container .image {
  width: 600px;
}
.landing .container .image > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*.....................not working..............................*/
.landing .container .text {
  flex: 1;
  background-color:red;
  /* not working */

  height: 100%;
}
/*................................not working...................*/
.landing .container .text > h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}
.landing .container .text > p {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #666;

}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Welcome, To Elzero World</h1>
          <p>
            Here Iam gonna share everything about my life. Books Iam reading,
            Games Iam Playing, Stories and Events
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img
            src="   https://elzerowebschool.github.io/HTML_And_CSS_Template_Three/imgs/landing-image.png"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#articles" class="go-down">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
```

**height:100; not working** why? when I set it to  (.landing .container .text ) it dosen't work
please help me.

I don't understand why this feature is not working

How do I deal with this problem please

and when i want to use calc(100% + 2px) ,it not working too

Comment: How can it be 100% when it is not the only child...it's not logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when it comes to percentage based heights in CSS, they only work if the parent element has a defined height. The most common issue with this comes from the `<html>` and `<body>` elements, which people usually don't set a height for and this can cause elements on the page to not properly use percentage based heights.

The other issue specific to your situation is that your `.landing` class has a `min-height` set, but not the `height`. Because of this, any child elements will not be able to use percentage based heights because the parent element doesn't not have a defined height.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.landing {
  position: relative;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 72px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.landing .container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height:100%;
}
.landing .container .image {
  width: 600px;
}
.landing .container .image > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*.....................not working..............................*/
.landing .container .text {
  flex: 1;

  /* not working */

  height: 100%;
}
/*................................not working...................*/
.landing .container .text > h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
}
.landing .container .text > p {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #666;

}
```

```html
<div class="landing">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text">
          <h1>Welcome, To Elzero World</h1>
          <p>
            Here Iam gonna share everything about my life. Books Iam reading,
            Games Iam Playing, Stories and Events
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img
            src="   https://elzerowebschool.github.io/HTML_And_CSS_Template_Three/imgs/landing-image.png"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#articles" class="go-down">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-double-down fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `min-height` on `.landing` to `height`, is this the effect you want?